# Visualizing a spline basis

Tags: data-visualization, splines

Textbooks typically have nice example plots of of the basis for uniform splines when they're explaining the topic.  Something like a row of little triangles for a linear spline, or a row of little humps for a cubic spline.

This is a typical example:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_introcom_a0000000525.htm

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to generate a plot of the spline basis using standard R functions (like bs or ns).  I guess there's some simple piece of matrix arithmetic combined with a trivial R program which will spit out a pretty plots of a spline basis in an elegant way. I just can't think of it!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this, as an example for B-splines:

```
x <- seq(0, 1, by=0.001)
spl <- bs(x,df=6)
plot(spl[,1]~x, ylim=c(0,max(spl)), type='l', lwd=2, col=1, 
     xlab="Cubic B-spline basis", ylab="")
for (j in 2:ncol(spl)) lines(spl[,j]~x, lwd=2, col=j)
```

Giving this:

[image]

Comment: It is a little more efficient to use the `matplot` function rather than looping through the columns.

Comment: So it is (+1), I don't know why I dropped it from my mental toolkit.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an [`autoplot` method](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/autoplot) for the "basis" class (which both bs and ns inherit from):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(reshape2)
library(stringr)
autoplot.basis <- function(basis, n=1000) {
    all.knots <- sort(c(attr(basis,"Boundary.knots") ,attr(basis, "knots"))) %>%
        unname
    bounds <- range(all.knots)
    knot.values <- predict(basis, all.knots) %>%
        set_colnames(str_c("S", seq_len(ncol(.))))
    newx <- seq(bounds[1], bounds[2], length.out = n+1)
    interp.values <- predict(basis, newx) %>%
        set_colnames(str_c("S", seq_len(ncol(.))))
    knot.df <- data.frame(x=all.knots, knot.values) %>%
        melt(id.vars="x", variable.name="Spline", value.name="y")
    interp.df <- data.frame(x=newx, interp.values) %>%
        melt(id.vars="x", variable.name="Spline", value.name="y")
    ggplot(interp.df) +
        aes(x=x, y=y, color=Spline, group=Spline) +
        geom_line() +
        geom_point(data=knot.df) +
        scale_color_discrete(guide=FALSE)
}
```

This lets you just call `autoplot` on an ns or bs object. Taking jbowman's example:

```
library(splines)
x <- seq(0, 1, by=0.001)
spl <- bs(x,df=6)
autoplot(spl)
```

which produces:

[image: Basis autoplot]

**Edit:** This will be included in the next version of the ggfortify package: https://github.com/sinhrks/ggfortify/pull/129. After that, I believe all you should need is:

```
library(splines)
library(ggfortify)
x <- seq(0, 1, by=0.001)
spl <- bs(x,df=6)
autoplot(spl)
```